# Postgresql throw null value in column violates not-null constraint when using oneToMany relationship in JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I tried to test one-to-many relationship for Hibernate. I defined Post and PostComment entities as below:
**Post.java**

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {

    @Id
    @Column(name="post_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long postId;

    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "post",
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<PostComment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

    public Post() {};

    public Post(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
   // Add getter and setter
}
```

**PostComment.java**

```
    import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "post_comment")
public class PostComment {
    @Id
    @Column(name="comment_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long commentId;

    @Column(name="review")
    private String review;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
    private Post post;

    public PostComment() {};
    public PostComment(String review) {
        this.review = review;
    }
    // Add getter and setter
}
```

**PostRepository.java**

```
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post,Long> {
}
```

and **db-changelog.xml**

```
<changeSet id="1" author="dev">
    <createTable tableName="post_comment">
        <column name="comment_id" type = "bigint">
            <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"></constraints>
        </column>
        <column name="review" type="varchar(255)"></column>
    </createTable>
    <createTable tableName="post">
        <column name="post_id" type="bigint">
            <constraints nullable="false" primaryKey="true"></constraints>
        </column>
        <column name="title" type = "varchar(255)"></column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

Then, I used SpringJUnit to add a new post as in PostServiceITTest.java

```
 import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;

import java.util.Arrays;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {Application.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
@ActiveProfiles("devmock")
public class PostServiceITTest {
    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    @Test
    public void testAddPost(){
        Post post = new Post(" Post 1");

        PostComment postComment1 = new PostComment(" Post comment 1");  
        PostComment postComment2 = new PostComment(" Post comment 2");
        post.setComments(Arrays.asList(postComment1,postComment2));

        postRepository.save(post);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the test throw a Postgresql error related to null-violate constraint:

```
    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "post_id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (null,  Post 1).
```

I greatly appreciate your time.

Comment: You did not pass a value for `post_id`.

Comment: Can you confirm the database tables have the column names you expect?

Comment: I'm sitting with the same problem. Any solution after a year and a half?

Answer (score 0):

In your `PostComment` class you have a field `private Post post`. I doubt if you are setting that field.

One option is to add `Post post` as a constructor argument to `PostComment` class (along with default constructor) and instantiating it along with `Post` object as in:

```
public PostComment(String review, Post post) {
  this.review = review;
  this.post = post;
}
```

and while constructing the object use :

```
PostComment postComment1 = new PostComment(" Post comment 1", post);
```

instead of

```
PostComment postComment1 = new PostComment(" Post comment 1");
```

Or another approach would be to add scaffolding code in `Post` class like:

```
public void addPostComment(PostComment comment) {
    comments.add(comment);
    comment.setPost(this);
}
```

and use this method while updating/adding a `PostComment` to the list in the `Post` class.

Comment: Thank your solutions. I did it with the exception 'null value in column "post_id" violates not-null constraint'. I am thinking about my liquibase.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by dropping my existed database and generating a new one with `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`. Of course, you can do it only if you have no valuable data in your database. Once you did it, change back to `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`.

Comment: This should not be downvoted, it certainly helps in comparing the newly generated tables with the once you create manually.

Answer (score 0):

Below code may work; you may set the parent reference in child also...

```
{       Post post = new Post(" Post 1");

        PostComment postComment1 = new PostComment(" Post comment 1");  
        postComment1.setPost(post); // < -- here
        PostComment postComment2 = new PostComment(" Post comment 2");
        postComment2.setPost(post); // < -- here

        post.setComments(Arrays.asList(postComment1,postComment2));

        postRepository.save(post); 
}
```

If you are using lombok to generate toString() method, please exclude postComment.post to avoid infinite loop (that leads to stak overflow);

```
@ToString(exclude = { "post" })
public class PostComment{
// ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you did not pass a value for `post_id`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I set post_id as auto @GeneratedValue. I think I do not need to add value to the post_id. Moreover, I tried to add " post.setPostId(1L);" after "Post post = new Post(" Post 1");" and run it again. New exception throws "Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column comments1_.post_id does not exist
  Position: 335"

Comment: Can you try saving the Post object first before you set the comments?

Comment: Yes, I tried to save it first, then update PostComment but the same exception 'column comments1_.post_id does not exist'