# getting not-null constraint error in hibernate one to many mapping

Tags: hibernate

so my user has one location such as:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "location_id")
private Location location = new Location();
```

and location table has:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="location", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<User> userSet = new HashSet<User>();
```

just running a simple insert into user table call
i keep running into this error:

```
Hibernate: insert into users (createdAt, email, firstName, gender, hashedPassword, lastName, location_id, type, updatedAt) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Mar 22, 2017 3:06:57 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502
Mar 22, 2017 3:06:57 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ERROR: null value in column "location_id" violates not-null constraint
Detail: Failing row contains (1, 2017-03-22 15:06:53.832, ankitv@uci.edu, ankit, null, turende, verma, 3, null, null).
2017-03-22 15:06:57.822:WARN::/bemh/medhuddleapi/userInfo/insertUser
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

any suggestions please..

Comment: Question can be improved by showing the constructor for Location, since it's called directly in the displayed code.  Relevant getters and setters for User.location and Location.userSet might also help.  Same with annotations on the Location.id attribute.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42327971/postgresql-throw-null-value-in-column-violates-not-null-constraint-when-using-on is also relevant.  Answers and comments there may help here.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the instantiation of `Location` from the User class.  https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/ seems to be a close analogue, but doesn't have the corresponding instantiation.

Alternately, confirm the columns created in the database have the names you expect.